# How to create a mock http.ServerRequest and http.ServerResponse?

Tags: node.js, testing

I've written a handler for `http.Server`'s [request event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request) (i.e. a function with signature `function (request, response) { ... }`) and I'd like to test it.  I'd like to do this via mock `http.ServerRequest` and `http.ServerResponse` objects.  How can I create these?

The obvious way doesn't seem to work:

```
$ node
> var http = require('http');
> new http.ServerRequest();
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at repl:1:9
...
```

Do I need to test this via a "real" HTTP server and client?

Comment: If you want to test it, then what's the harm in doing it the real way.

Comment: @user568109 Well the code itself has no network dependency, so it seems unnecessary (and slower) for the tests to need the network.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's at least two projects that allow mocking of `http.ServerRequest` and `http.ServerResponse`: https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http and https://github.com/vojtajina/node-mocks.

And for some reason it does seem to be more common to test via real HTTP request; https://github.com/flatiron/nock seems to be the tool to use here.

See also [node.js: Mock http request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021956/node-js-mock-http-request-and-response).

Comment: `node-mocks-http` seems fairly limited as it doesn't allow you to write to the request body as a stream

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using [http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.12/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback). It allows you to issue requests from server, so you can test it with your code. If you want to send simple GET request you can use [http.get](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.12/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) , which is easier. Otherwise you would have to construct your request yourself. Example from docs :

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

If you are using [request](https://npmjs.org/package/request) you can do the same.

```
var request = require('request');
request.post( url, json_obj_to_pass,
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
            console.log(body)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple and basic mock for `http.ServerResponse`, the gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/daithi-coombes/8039142) and for `http.ServerRequest` I use [rewire](https://npmjs.org/package/rewire).

Firstly load dependencies:

```
var require = require('rewire'),
    events = require('events'),
    util = require('util');
```

This is the `http.ServerResponse` mock. It basically creates an object with the same methods as http.ServerResponse, and then the `events` module is inherited using the `util` module.

```
/**
 * Mock https.serverResponse
 * @type {Object}
 */
var mockResponse;
Eventer = function(){
    events.EventEmitter.call(this);

    this.data = '';

    this.onData = function(){
        this.emit('data', this.data);
    }

    this.setEncoding = function(){

    }

    this.onEnd = function(){
        this.emit('end', this.data);
    }

    this.run = function(){
        this.onData();
        this.onEnd();
    }
};
util.inherits(Eventer, events.EventEmitter);
```

I then use this mock with rewire to override the http module's get(), request() or any other library.

```
/**
 * Mocks literal object for rewire mocking.
 * @see https://github.com/jhnns/rewire
 * @type {Object}
 */
var mocks = {
    "https" : {
        "get" : function(url, fn){
            fn(mockResponse.data);
            mockResponse.run();
        }
    }
};

//instead of: var myModule = require('myModule');
//do:
var myModule = rewire('myModule');
myModule.__set__(mocks);
```

Now the `http` library in your module is mocked