# Testing route with fake session in node js

Tags: node.js, testing, express, nodeunit, superagent

I am using node js + express for my server. I am writing test with superagent + node unit, my routes needs session for accessing it, can I fake this session for testing my route/controller? (May be superagent don't have this functionality, so suggest please another tool)

Comment: Did you tried with superagent? ("May be it don t have" != "It don t have")

Comment: @DrakaSAN I don't find it in it's API

Comment: Well I m not web develloper, but it seems the sessions is supposed to be created by node on the server, not on the client (nb: I don t know what is testing route)

Comment: @DrakaSAN route is module handling requests to my server. Superagent can send it to my server, a lot of developers use it for test purposes, to check how some url requested works under real requests. So you can fake real session for test user profile for example, I did it, but not in node js, and now I am asking about it

Comment: Well I m afraid I can t help you more, I never done any http server with node.js, nor ever used superagent, hope someone will be able to answer you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a mock http.ServerRequest and http.ServerResponse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15022544/how-to-create-a-mock-http-serverrequest-and-http-serverresponse)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an minimal working example using `express-session`:

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");

const app = express();
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }),
);

app.post("/signin", (req, res) => {
  req.session.auth = "123";
  console.info("sign in success");
  res.status(200).end();
});

app.get("/protected", (req, res) => {
  console.log("req.session.auth: ", req.session.auth);
  if (!req.session.auth) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  res.json({ data: "protected data" });
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const superagent = require("superagent");
const { expect } = require("chai");

describe("21040811", () => {
  let server;
  const port = 4001;
  const agent = superagent.agent();
  before((done) => {
    server = app.listen(port, () => {
      console.info(`HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
      done();
    });
  });
  after((done) => {
    server.close(done);
  });
  it("should return 401 status code", () => {
    return agent.get(`http://localhost:${port}/protected`).catch((err) => {
      expect(err.response.status).to.be.equal(401);
    });
  });

  it("should sign in success and access /protected API correctly", () => {
    return agent
      .post(`http://localhost:${port}/signin`)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
      })
      .then(() => agent.get(`http://localhost:${port}/protected`))
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.status).to.be.equal(200);
        expect(res.body).to.be.eql({ data: "protected data" });
      });
  });
});
```

Integration test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 21040811
HTTP server is listening on http://localhost:4001
req.session.auth:  undefined
    ✓ should return 401 status code
sign in success
req.session.auth:  123
    ✓ should sign in success and access /protected API correctly


  2 passing (61ms)

-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File         |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files    |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.js      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 app.test.js |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
-------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/21040811